# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'to_float'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a machine learning model for automatic segmentation of the heart. I use tensorflow 2.8.0. Here is a piece of my code:

```
for step in range(steps):
    print('\n****** Epoch {} Step {} ******'.format(epoch, step))
    batch_img0, batch_img1, batch_mask0, batch_mask1 = next(train_generator)
    print(model.train_on_batch([batch_img0, batch_img1, batch_mask0], batch_mask1, sample_weight=None, class_weight=None))
```

At the level of this for loop, I receive the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\talba\Downloads\base de données\CardiacMotionFlow-master\segmentation\finetune_lvrv_net.py", line 323, in finetune_lvrv_net
    print(model.train_on_batch([batch_img0, batch_img1, batch_mask0], 
  File "C:\Users\talba\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2093, in train_on_batch
    logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\talba\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\talba\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1147, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\talba\Downloads\jupiter\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\talba\Downloads\base de données\CardiacMotionFlow-master\segmentation\..\helpers.py", line 1356, in dice_coef5_0  *
        y_pred = tf.to_float(y_pred)

    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'to_float'
```

The error is apparently at the level of this line

```
print(model.train_on_batch([batch_img0, batch_img1, batch_mask0], batch_mask1, sample_weight=None, class_weight=None))
```

And I receive the attribute error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'to_float'`
yet I did not write a line with float in my code. I do not understand. Please can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Intead of using the train_on_batch, method on your object model. Try using fit(), also check to see if there is no such lines in your code. y_pred = tf.to_float(y_pred)

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the file which contains to_float. I changed it to to_cast and my code worked. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tf.to_float(x),
Use tf.cast(x,tf.float32)